# Using Requirejs modules in Phantomjs

Tags: javascript, requirejs, phantomjs, amd, commonjs

I am new to both RequireJs and Phantomjs. Anyhow, I am trying to use Requirejs modules in Phantomjs. I have written the following code:

```
var page = require("webpage").create();
page.open("about:blank");
page.injectJs("require.js", function(){
    require("main.js");    
    phantom.exit();
});
```

I have also tried it this way, but still with no luck:

```
var page = require("webpage").create();
page.open("about:blank");
page.injectJs("./require.js");
page.injectJs("./main.js");
phantom.exit();
```

main.js is a requirejs module. So what I am trying to achieve is that I wish to write some code that I can use in my browser and then use it as in PhantomJs without any changes. Unfortunately, it seems PhantomJs doesn't like it. It just "hangs" and doesn't display anything. Any tips on how I can accomplish this without going through tools like Browserify, etc.?

Comment: You probably want to call `require("main.js");` inside of the page context: `page.evaluate(function(){require("main.js");});`. I'm not sure what you want to achieve. You can also remove the line `page.open("about:blank");`, because it isn't doing anything.

Comment: @ArtjomB. I am just trying to reuse RequireJs modules in PhantomJs. I tried putting require("main.js") in page.evaluate, but still no difference. I think the problem arises because I am trying to include require.js and this comes in conflict with PhantomJs CommonsJs require.

Comment: What kind of modules are those? Do you need access do the `document`? PhantomJS has a page context (which is sandboxed) and a phantom context. It is necessary to know where you want to execute your module. Your first snippet hangs because `page.injectJs` doesn't have a callback. RequireJS takes care of the loading of modules, so injecting (into the page context) them yourself isn't doing anything. Also, when you are on the `about:blank` requirejs cannot find the correct module.